# Show that$\displaystyle \sum_{t \ge 0} \binom{n}{j+t} \binom{m}{k+t} = \binom {m+n}{n+k-j}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

$$\sum_{t \ge 0} \binom{n}{j+t} \binom{m}{k+t} = \binom {m+n}{n+k-j}$$

Can anybody provide me an idea of a combinatorical proof of this identity. I can deduce it algebraically, but I could not find a suitable combinatorical proof. I want a practical scenario to prove this.

Comment: It looks like it isn't true, if $j=n$ and $k=m$ it reduces to $$1=\binom{m+n}m$$

Comment: j, k are to be assumed strictly less than n, m, respectively. I didn't mention that as I thought this was assumable. Should have mentioned it

Comment: if $j=n-1$ and $k=m-1$ it reduces to $$1+mn=\binom{m+n}m$$

Comment: You want to take the summation over all $t$ (including **negative** values) for which the LHS makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If we remove the restriction on $t$, the LHS becomes

$$\sum_{t} \binom{n}{j+t} \binom{m}{k+t} = \sum_{t} \binom{n}{n-j-t} \binom{m}{k+t}$$

Then the LHS counts the number of ways of selecting $(n-j-t) +(k+t) = n-j+k$ items from $n+m$ items.

Comment: Actually I want a thinking involving all the parameters m,n,j,k. Any good scenario for that. We can manipulate in some ways to get a good form, but I want to keep it as it is.